# Type instance and phantom type

Tags: haskell, ghc, servant, phantom-types, type-synonyms

I ran into a strange error, I cannot find a way to fix it. I’m using servant and I am trying to build a generic authentication library (no backend by default, for instance).

The code is the following:

```
type TokenProtect auth = AuthProtect "auth-token"
type instance AuthServerData (TokenProtect auth) = Id auth
```

`Id` is another type family. The error message is the following.

```
    • Family instance purports to bind type variable ‘auth’
        but the real LHS (expanding synonyms) is:
          AuthServerData (AuthProtect "auth-token") = ...
    • In the type instance declaration for ‘AuthServerData’
```

Do you know how I can fix this code?

Comment: `TokenProtect` is a type synonym and does not use `auth` on the right hand side. If you expand the type synonym in the second line, you get `type instance AuthServerData (AuthProtect "auth-token") = Id auth`, so `auth` on the right-hand side is effectively unbound.

Comment: There's no way to tell how to 'fix' this without having some broader context as to what this type family is trying to accomplish. You could e.g. add a parameter to `AuthServerData`: `type instance AuthServerData (AuthProtect "auth-token") auth = Id auth`

Comment: I'm pretty sure the fix is using `newtype` instead of `type`.

Comment: Type synonyms are *almost never* what you really want. Honestly, the only uses I find really convincing are higher-rank ones, as seen in `lens`. In most simple cases, the discipline required to make type synonyms helpful is just not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to turn `TokenProtect` into a `newtype` wrapper:

```
newtype TokenProtect auth = TokenProtect (AuthProtect "auth-token")
type instance AuthServerData (TokenProtect auth) = Id auth
```

The reason for that is that type synonyms are just that: synonyms; so your code is equivalent to writing

```
type instance AuthServerData (AuthProtect "auth-token") = Id auth
```

which of course refers to the unbound type variable `auth`.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the issue using Servant, and I think my use case was similar to the original questioner's. Basically I wanted AuthProtect to allow me to thread a type constrained by some type synonym provided by a class through to my handlers, like

```
class IsDatabase db where 
   type DatabaseAuthResult db :: *
instance IsDatabase MyDBType
   type DatabaseAuthResult MyDBType = DBUser
```

Therefore needing something like the original poster's code:

```
type TokenProtect db = AuthProtect "auth-token"
type instance AuthServerData (TokenProtect db) = DatabaseAuthResult db
```

As far as I can work out, this is simply not possible within the structure of Servant's [general auth implementation](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2016-10-25/servant-server-0.9.0.1/Servant-Server-Experimental-Auth.html#t:AuthHandler). Cactus' answer correctly says that you have to wrap the existential in a newtype, but that in itself will simply lead to a compilation error to do with Servant constraints, probably some issue with a `HasServer` instance.

There is a general answer to this issue, however, which is simply to replicate Servant's `AuthProtect`, `AuthHandler` etc with your own implementation, and write your own version of HasServer for it.

```
-- import for all the internal servant stuff like addAuthCheck
import Servant.Server.Internal.RoutingApplication

data DBAuthProtect (tag :: k) db deriving (Typeable)
newtype DBAuthHandler r db result = DBAuthHandler {unDBAuthHandler :: r -> Handler result}

instance ( HasServer api context
         , HasContextEntry context (DBAuthHandler Request db (AuthServerData (DBAuthProtect tag db))))
  => HasServer (DBAuthProtect tag db :> api) context where
  type ServerT (DBAuthProtect tag db :> api) m = AuthServerData (DBAuthProtect tag db) -> ServerT api m
  route Proxy context subserver = 
    route (Proxy :: Proxy api) context (subserver `addAuthCheck` withRequest authCheck)
      where 
       authHandler :: Request -> Handler (AuthServerData (DBAuthProtect tag db))
       authHandler = unDBAuthHandler (getContextEntry context)
       authCheck :: Request -> DelayedIO (AuthServerData (DBAuthProtect tag db))
       authCheck = (>>= either delayedFailFatal return) . liftIO . runExceptT . authHandler
```

You can then use this similarly to `AuthProtect`, so something like

```
type TokenProtect db = DBAuthProtect "auth-token" db
type instance AuthServerData (TokenProtect db) = DatabaseAuthResult db
type ProtectedAPI db = "private" :> TokenProtect db :> Get [...]
dbAuthHandler :: (IsDatabase db) => db -> DBAuthHandler Request db (DatabaseAuthResult db)
dbAuthHandler db = DBAuthHandler $ \ req -> do 
  -- req :: Request
  -- ... do some work here and return a type (DatabaseAuthResult db), so for MyDBType you would return DBUser - you have both the db itself and the request to work with
```

Finally you put this all together by using Servant's `serveWithContext` and in the context you provide the handler partially applied

```
mkContext :: db -> Context '[DBAuthHandler Request db (AuthServerData db)]
mkContext db = dbAuthHandler db :. EmptyContext

main :: IO ()
main = do 
  db <- getMyDBSomehow -- a concrete type, say MyDBType
  let myApi = (Proxy :: Proxy (ProtectedAPI MyDBType))
  serveWithContext myApi (mkContext db) handlers
```

Basically the way this works is to thread a type variable through the various bits and pieces so you end up with an api parameterised by a db type (similarly for handlers), allowing you to use type synonyms in your api type and therefore in your handlers.

If you are using a custom monad for your app you can improve on this pattern by using `enter` when running your authHandler (and add any context your app monad needs to the context you pass to you `serveWithContext`, but that is beyond the scope of this question...).